# Odd transactions not updating with PayPal Response

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have an ASP.Net website which has been running for a number of years.

The site is configured with PayPal payment where I send a HTML request with the details to PP. This shows the page to login and pay. Once a successful payment is made the user is automatically redirected back to a thankyou page to update the database with the transaction details ([www.example.com/orders/thanks](http://www.example.com/orders/thanks)).

On this PP account, I have set:

**Instant Payment Notifications**

*Instant Payment Notification (IPN) which is pointing to an URL ([www.example.com/orders/thanks](http://www.example.com/orders/thanks)) on the site to process the transaction.

Receive IPN messages is enabled.*

**Website payment preferences**
Auto Return is on (set to the same URL as the IPN ([www.example.com/orders/thanks](http://www.example.com/orders/thanks)))

*PDT (Payment Data Transfer) is enabled*

Strangely for **some** transactions (I'm taking a guess here as I don't know why this is happening), the response isn't hitting the URL so it cant update the order. I go into IPN history and can see the transaction for a successful order but for whatever reason, odd transactions never update the database.

Under my development machine, if I copy the IPN message from PP (Under IPN history) and send it manually via a debugger, it updates the db fine, so I originally thought the IPN message may have had some encoding issue but might not be the case.

Does anyone know what might be missing here in order to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add logging to your IPN handler (the code at the listener URL) to record what happens when it receives IPNs from PayPal.  Maybe it's not able to validate the IPN at that time, or maybe there's some other error -- but you won't know until you add complete logging to find out.

You can also review your webserver logs and ensure you see events for when PayPal sent the original IPN message (according to IPN history)

---

If you're interested in updating your checkout to a proper server API-based integration that doesn't depend on asynchronous callbacks like IPN, implement two routes for 'Create Order' and 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return JSON data, and the latter should (on successful capture) record the transaction in your database before doing the return.

Pair your two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server